# Using the same code multiple times on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am new at iOS Development. Here i have problem with using the same code different times so how to implement oops concept in iPhone.

```
sharebuttonpress = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
sharebuttonpress.frame = CGRectMake(330, 800, 145, 85);

[sharebuttonpress setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"share_new.png"]
                        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sharebuttonpress addTarget:self action:@selector(sharePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:sharebuttonpress];

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:sharebuttonpress];
```

Comment: What do u want to achieve ??? Please explain in detail...

Answer (score 1):

**Methods** will do

You have to Learn Objective-C before going to develop an application.

Read the basics from [Apple.Developer site](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html) . Read the section ***Methods and Messaging***

**Example:**

```
-(void)createMyButton{

  sharebuttonpress = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  sharebuttonpress.frame = CGRectMake(330, 800, 145, 85);

  [sharebuttonpress setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"share_new.png"]
                        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [sharebuttonpress addTarget:self action:@selector(sharePressed:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [self.view addSubview:sharebuttonpress];

  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:sharebuttonpress];

}
```

call the method wherever you need as

```
[self createMyButton];
```

Read **advance document** [here](https://intellisenze.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/code-reuse-in-objective-c/) about Code Reuse in Objective C